# Получить user id в header.tpl Opencart 2

Tags: opencart

Получить user email в header.tpl Opencart 2

```
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $data['customer_id'] = $this->customer->getId(); // customer ID
    $data['customer_fname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName(); // customer email
    }
```

не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

`$data['customer_email'] = $this->customer->getEmail();`

Answer (score 0):

В файле контроллера `catalog/controller/common/headep.php`:

```
$data['any_name'] = $this->customer->getEmail();
```

В файле представления `catalog/view/theme/your_theme/common/header.tpl`:

```
<?=$any_name;?>
```

Вы тянете не те данные:
 `$data['customer_fname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName(); // даст имя

Comment: спс, до конца не разобрался как потсить правильно.